# responsive buttongroup buttons in material ui + reactjs app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

How to achieve responsive ButtonGroup Buttons? I found some information that material-ui's ButtonGroup can use an attribute called "Orientation" but I don't understand how to use it with media queries which means changing its orientation in real-time when the device has a narrow width etc. I'm new to this so bear with me.

```
import './App.css';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import ButtonGroup from '@material-ui/core/ButtonGroup';
import Container from '@material-ui/core/Container';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import useMediaQuery from '@material-ui/core/useMediaQuery';
import { MuiThemeProvider, createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { deepPurple, purple } from '@material-ui/core/colors';

const dvTheme = createMuiTheme({ palette: { primary: deepPurple } });
const bvTheme = createMuiTheme({ palette: { primary: purple } });

function App() {
    return (

    <div className="App">
          <MuiThemeProvider theme={bvTheme}>
              <div className="App-header">  
                  <h1 id="header-text">Web Programming</h1>
              </div>
          </MuiThemeProvider>
          <MuiThemeProvider theme={dvTheme}>
                <div className="header-buttons">
                    <ButtonGroup variant="contained" size="large" className="btngrp" color="primary">
              <Button>Overview</Button>
              <Button>Features</Button>
              <Button>Details</Button>
              <Button>Technology</Button>
              <Button>FAQ</Button>
                  </ButtonGroup> 
              </div>
            </MuiThemeProvider>
            <Container>       
                <div className="main">
                    <Grid container justify="center">
                       
                        <Grid item id="feature-vid">
                            <video width="300" height="240" controls>
                                </video>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item id="feature-paragraph">
                            <h1 id="feature-text">Features</h1>
                            <p>
                                Dolore ex deserunt aute fugiat aute nulla ea sunt aliqua nisi cupidatat eu. Nostrud in laboris labore nisi amet do dolor eu fugiat consectetur elit cillum esse.
                                </p>
                            <a href="#" id="feature-link">READ OUR FEATURES</a>
                        </Grid>   
                    </Grid>
                </div>
            </Container>

            <Container spacing={0}>
                <Grid container>
                <Grid item>
                    <h2>Details</h2>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </Container>

    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Comment: Orientation is the layout of the buttons. Default is horizontal and alternate option is vertical as seen [here](https://material-ui.com/components/button-group/#vertical-group).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to specify the criteria for mediquery as below:

```
  const matches = useMediaQuery("(min-width:600px)");
```

Then change the orientation based on the value of matches:

```
  orientation={`${matches ? `horizontal` : `vertical`}`}
```

as you can see in this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-wiles-n1r60?file=/src/App.js:1063-1130) link, the `orientation` of the `ButtonGroup` is horizontal when the width is higher than 600px and it's vertical for the lower width values.

You can also read [here](https://material-ui.com/components/use-media-query/) about the Media queries in Material UI, and [here](https://material-ui.com/api/button-group/) about the ButtonGroup APIs and props.

Comment: It works, thank you kind sir, I learned quite an important thing from you.